# how to acess return the for loop value from one function to other function pythin3?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a function named SumofSquares internally I am calling Square function passing list values.I want to iterate in Square Function and send back each for loop data into SumofSquares Please suggests me some way

```
def Square(Array): 
    for  data in Array:
         return data

 
def SumofSquares(Array):
   SquaredValue = Square(Array)
   
Array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
Total = SumofSquares(Array)
```

Comment: For one thing you spelled `yield` wrong. And if you want the generator to return a value it should be: `yield data * data`

Answer (score 1):

Your original question had the `yield` (spelled wrong) but you removed it for some reason. You need the `yield` and it needs to return a value:

```
def square(array): 
    for data in array:
        yield data * data
 
def sum_of_squares(array):
    return sum(square(array))
  
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
total = sum_of_squares(array)
```

But the way you are doing things, you don't need the generator at all.

```
def sum_of_squares(array):
    return sum(x * x for x in array)

array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
total = sum_of_squares(array)
```

Both examples produce the same result.

Note, I changed some names to be more in line with [Python naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 0):

Just return a list including the results you want to return :

```
def Square(Array): 
    res = []
    for  data in Array:
         res.append(pow(data, 2))
    return (res)

def SumofSquares(Array):
    res = 0
    for k in Array:
        res += k
    return (res)

Array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
Total = SumofSquares(Array)
```

I also added the pow(data, 2) in your Square function (similar to data**2), because it seemed like you forgot it in your problem, feel free to remove it if I misunderstood